# How to change color of Text Box when validation is incorrect in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a below Div which consist of an input box

```
  return (
  <div class="textBoxContainer input-container">
      <div class="field textContainer">
        <input id={props.id} type={type} placeholder=' ' onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={createValidator(type)} 
        className={textContainerClassDisabled.join(' ')} disabled={props.textContainerDisabled} />
        <label for={props.id}>{placeholder}</label>
        <span className={boxClass.join(' ')} onClick={showHide}>
          {type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
        </span>
         <p>{isValid}</p> 
      </div>
  </div>
   )
```

I want to add 'error' class to 'div class="textBoxContainer input-container">'

```
.error {
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

Below is the Conditional Statement:

```
switch (type) {
    case 'email':
        return (e) => {
           email=e.target.value;
           //var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
           if(!emailReg.test(email)) {
            isValid=true;
            console.log("Please enter a valid email address");
           }
           else{
            isValid=false;
            console.log("Correct");
           }
         }
```

where:

```
 let isValid=false;
 type=email;
```

I am not able to dynamically change the color of the border of my text box when isValid condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `isValid` through as a prop to your component, and then conditionally add the `.error` class to `className={textContainerClassDisabled.join(' ')}` based on the value of `isValid`

Answer (score 0):

You can import classnames from 'classnames'
`import classNames from 'classnames';`

```
<div class="textBoxContainer input-container">
      <div class="field textContainer">
        <input id={props.id} type={type} placeholder=' ' onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={createValidator(type)} 
        className={textContainerClassDisabled.join(' ')} disabled={props.textContainerDisabled} />
        <label for={props.id}>{placeholder}</label>
        <span className={classNames({type==="input" ? "your class":"else other class"})
onClick={showHide}>

         <p>{isValid}</p> 
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way,
className = 'textBoxContainer input-container'

```
<div class="className">
```

and switch section,

```
if(!emailReg.test(email)) {
        isValid=true;
        className += ' error';
        console.log("Please enter a valid email address");
       }
       else{
        isValid=false;
        className = 'textBoxContainer input-container';
        console.log("Correct");
       }
```

Comment: styles is not defined is coming

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to import the `classnames` library you could use string templates and a ternary to achieve the same thing:

```
<div className={`textBoxContainer input-container ${isValid? 'valid_class' : 'invalid_class'}`}>
      ...
</div>
```

Side note: I find it confusing that you set isValid to true when the email is *invalid*. I'd consider switching that around so it's easier to read.

Comment: `valid_class` and `invalid_class` were just examples. You'd need to update them to the classes you use to style valid/invalid divs.

Also I noticed in your example you are using `class` instead of `className`. Are you writing a React Component as implied in your title, or HTML? If it is React to my knowledge you need to use `className`.

Comment: I am using className and with my css classes. The issue is that changed isValid value is not updating ${isValid?  here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone, I am able to sort it out.

```
const [isValid, setIsValid]=useState(true);

const wrongInput=(a)=>{
    setIsValid(a);
};

if(!emailReg.test(email)) {
    wrongInput(false);
    console.log("Please enter a valid email address");
}
else{
    wrongInput(true);
    console.log("Correct");
}

<div className={`textBoxContainer input-container ${isValid? '' : 'error'}`}>
```